# @ mark at php causing loss of performance?

Tags: php, performance

I use @ mark in many block (where necessary). I heard it causes loss of performance.Is it true?If it is true, Is there another way for @ function

Comment: Please provide an example usage of you using `@` to answer the second part of your question

Comment: I can't imagine that it would cost so much performance that there's a reason to avoid it. That said, it suppressed warning, which *should* in general be avoided. So do avoid using `@` if possible, but for a different reason.

Comment: See [this article](http://seanmonstar.com/post/909029460/php-error-suppression-performance) for an explanation of your performance loss.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can suppress a warning like this:

```
@$value = $_GET['value'];
```

but you can also just check if the key exists

```
if (isset($_GET['value']))
  $value = $_GET['value'];
```

or

```
if (array_key_exists('value', $_GET))
  $value = $_GET['value'];
```

I prefer the latter, because I think it's the purest form.